# LocalStorage cleared only on refresh and not on click using vuejs methods

Tags: vue.js

Want to clear TODO list's local storage on click.

It's working but the list becomes empty only when I refresh the page. The problem is that I want it to show when I click it, not when I refresh the page.

```html
<button class="btn delete-all-btn" @click="deleteToDo()">Supprimer</button>
```

```js
methods: {
  deleteToDo() {
    localStorage.removeItem('todos')
  }
},
```

Comment: you need to also clear the vue model which holds the loaded items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty the data bound to template. For example, if you bind an array `todos` to template:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(todo, i) in todos" :key="i">{{...}}</div>
</template>

<script>
/*...*/
  methods: {
    deleteToDo() {
      localStorage.removeItem('todos')
      this.todos = []  // add this line
    }
  },
/*...*/
</script>
```